# sending error message to view with codeigniter

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, post

I have a form that submit `email` and have a condition if the submitted email isn't verified (status = 1) then it fails to insert to the `user_driver` table. What I want to achieve is how can I show error message like "Please verify your email" when the user click on `add` button after filling the email field? I am using jquery to send input post to controller and my form is inside `modal` bootstrap. It hits `success` function even though the requirement is not met (`email_verified = 1`) and then `reload` the page. So, I am a bit confuse how to show the error message.

**My view:**

```js
function add_driver()
{
    user_email = $("#user_email").val();
    $.ajax
    ({
            url : site_url+'portal/add_driver',
            type: "POST",
            //dataType: "json",
            data:{user_email: user_email},
            success: function(data)
            {     
                $("#add_driver_modal").modal("hide");
                location.reload();
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                alert('Email already registered');
                location.reload();
            }
    });
};
```

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="add_driver_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
          <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">ADD DRIVER</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body" id='add'>
                <div class="row" id="add_driver_form">
                
                    <input type="hidden" name="user_id" id="user_id" />

                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" autocomplete="off" id="user_email"  name="user_email"  placeholder="Email" required>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button id="add" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" onclick=add_driver()>Add</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="form_submit_result"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

**My controller:**

```
public function add_driver()
{
    $user_email = $this->input->post('user_email');

    $array = array(
        'user_email' => $user_email,
        'email_verified' => 1,
        'phone_verified' => 1
        );

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->where($array);
    $this->db->from('user');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->row_array();
    $match_id = $result['user_id'];
    $match_email = $result['user_email'];

    if(!is_null($result))
    {
        $data_user_driver = array(
            'user_id' => $match_id,
            'user_email' => $match_email
            );
        $this->db->insert('user_driver',$data_user_driver);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may add a `p` tag in your modal inside `modal-body` like

```
....
<div class="modal-body" id='add'>
 <p style="display:none;" id="error" class="alert alert-danger"></p>
...
```

and add a `else` block and send any message if no result found (in add_driver method) like

```
...
if(!is_null($result)){
        $data_user_driver = array(
            'user_id' => $match_id,
            'user_email' => $match_email
            );
        $this->db->insert('user_driver',$data_user_driver);
    } else {//if email not verified 
      echo 'err';
    }
....
```

Now check this result in your ajax `success`

```
....
success: function(data){
         if(data == 'err'){
           $('#error').show().text('Please verify your email');
           return false;
         }
         $('#error').hide();     
         $("#add_driver_modal").modal("hide");
         location.reload();
 },
 ....
```

Comment: never thought about that. Thanks a lot ! :)